# Map application in iphone

Tags: iphone

requirement of my app is to set a user current location and wherever he travels his that  position should be mark and then he should get entire rout in iphone.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Then perhaps you should play with [Map Kit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html) and [Core Location](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/index.html).

Comment: I have used both of this but i m not getting clear idea.can u help me with a code,please.
Thanks theatrus.